# data mining from website using xpath in python

Tags: python, xpath, lxml

I run this program but it is giving me only "[]" instead of giving the web page data.please help

```
import urllib 
   import re
   import lxml.html

   start_link= "http://aepcindia.com/ApparelMarketplaces/detail"
   html_string = urllib.urlopen(start_link)
   dom =  lxml.html.fromstring(html_string.read())
   side_bar_link = dom.xpath("//*[@id='show_cont']/div/table/tr[2]/td[2]/text()")
   print side_bar_link 
   file = open("next_page.txt","w")
   for link in side_bar_link:
       file.write(link)
       print link

   file.close()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTML source you are downloading contains an empty content area: `<div id="show_cont"></div>`. This `div` is populated later by a `javascript` function `showData()`. When you look at the page in a browser, the javascript is executed before, which is not the case when you just download the HTML source using `urllib`.

To get the data you want, you can try to mimic the `POST` request in the `showData()` function or, preferably, scrape the website using a scriptable headless browser.

**Update:** While a headless browser would be a much more generally applicable approach, in this case it might be overhead here. You actually will be better off reverse engineering the `showData()` function. The alax-call in that is all too obvious, delivers a plain HTML table and you can also limit searches :)
`http://aepcindia.com/ApparelMarketplaces/ajax_detail/search_type:/search_value:`

Comment: @Bam Feel invited to mark the answer as correct ;o)